# Adding Payments to Printed Invoice in Acumatica Report Designer

Tags: reporting, acumatica, subreport

### The Problem

Accounts Receivable has asked me to add (pre)payments to the invoices they send out because customers are paying twice (when they pre-pay and then when they get the invoice). They have tried sending receipts of payments with the invoice, but the double payments are still happening. Plus, as the head of Accounting said, "If doctor bills can show payments, why can't we? The pre-payments are applied in the system to an invoice but why is there no way to include that on the invoice?"

### My Investigation

The Invoice report form has ARTran entity as the detail lines on any given invoice. However, ARTran only includes the itemized lines created for an invoice (usually from a link Sales Order) and not the applied payments. Applied payments are in the table ARAdjst which has no correlation to ARTran. So, my immediate thought is that a subreport is needed. Acumatica's help files say in order to add subreport, the report definition file needs to be in the same file on the server as the main report definition and that the subreport needs to have the same report parameters as the main report.

### Proposed Solution

Create a subreport for ARAdjst for an invoice and total the payments in the subreport at the bottom of the main report. Let the subreport be visible only if there are payments. Subtract the payment total from the invoicing total, which is what Accounting really wants.

### How It's Going

I have created a simple report called Adjustments that has the same parameters as the invoice and shows the ARAdjst for the invoice and sums the total for payments. I added the subreport to the Invoice report and linked them via parameters. I haven't even tried to get the sum of Adjustments to a field on the Invoice. I also added the Adjustments report to the server via the Report Designer (which puts the definition in the database) and by copying the file to reports folder on the server because that's what the help says to do. It crashes every time I try to run invoices in Acumatica. I also had to remove the group footer on invoice that I added for the Adjustments subreport, because I was getting an error even if I rolled back to a different version. I've considered the fact that since it's not a system report, that might be why it won't let me add it as a subreport. There are no system reports that show (pre)payments beyond AR Detail or AR Register, both of which are not what I'm looking for.

### My Plea

Has anyone added a non-system report as an Acumatica subreport before and had the addition work? If yes, how?

I'm feeling like this solution is dead in the water, right now. And I never thought I would see the day when I miss Crystal Reports, ha. I was going to take screenshots of the report layouts, but obviously, there is more to it than that or it would be working.

Comment: I added more explanation to my answer. In short, built-in sub-report should behave like the custom one added to reports folder.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing really special with built-in sub-reports.
You need to have 2 rpx files in reports folder for report and sub-report.
Then you put a SubReport element in the main Report.

[image]

Passing the parameters is the most tricky part. Reference: https://help-2018r1.acumatica.com/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=da5f4cca-6435-4400-a814-8d74ae813986

Maybe I'm wrong but from what I know, you can pass a parameter from Report to Sub-Report:
[image]

But you can't pass the parameter from Sub-Report to Report:
[image]

To display the total of Sub-Report in the Report I would add a new custom field to the report DAC (invoice) that sums the pre-payments. This custom field can be initialized with the desired value in many ways. For example, using a field attribute like PXFormula/PXDBCalc or with a FieldSelecting event.

Comment: My issue ended up being that I was using fields from ARAdjust in my Filters of the Report Data that don't exist in the DAC definition for the entity in Acumatica. I got around it by using similar fields. I really have never worked with DACs before but I'll definitely need to add a Payment Total field to use at the end of the invoice.

Comment: If you run into similar issues again, you can try removing elements of the report one by one until error disappears to find the root cause. It's also possible to open RPX file in a standard text editor to inspect it's entire content quickly. This can help determine whether a DAC is used or not in a Report.

Comment: To add field you would be looking into creating a DAC extension and a customization project to deploy it. In Report designer you can refresh the tables in Build Schema dialog after the DAC extension is deployed to see the new fields.